# Multiple functions over a list

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of records/tuple. and a couple of functions that process on list. like max_min that takes a list and return min,max pair. 
Is there any way to combine these functions without modification?
Each function will not do any modification to original list.
But might do reduce, map, filter.

```
    stream ---> Process1 ----> Process2

    [ (x:4,y:2,value:10) , (x:3,y:1,value:2), ... ]

    function min_max (list) = .... a function that takes a list and return (min,max) pair

    function count(list) = .... count occurrences and return [(item, times)]
    function average(list) = ....
```

In imperative way, I could just use a big for loop and include all logics of each function inside.
Is there any elegant way to do this?

In python, generator send could send each list element to all functions. I think that might work.
How would one abstract this in functional way? monad? fold?

Comment: What programming language is this question about? Perl, Python or Haskell? Please remove the language tags that do not apply.

Comment: min/max/count - would go in one fold where the folding function consists of the used functions, the average would not go in one fold - as the division operation of sum and len cannot fit in the fold - but it can be easily done afterwards

Comment: but I recommend starting with a simple - doing every step after the other programm - <strike>see</strike> measure if it is fast enough (if you're using haskell I'd recommend 'criterion'), and only if it is not - then start writing a composed folding function - and document what it does and why you have chosen to do so (e.g. for performance reasons)

Comment: You want to write a "combined" version of several functions so that you can compute it with only one loop/fold over the list. This may or may not be feasible depending on which functions you want to combine. Further, the question is not so clear: what should "without modification" require? Maybe you just want to write `combine(fun1,fun2,...)` and have a single-fold function being crafted automatically. I don't think this can be done easily unless `fun1,..` have some special form.

Comment: @simbabque  it doesn't matter which programming language. it's not a programming language specific question.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, the easy way is to use Gabriel Gonzalez's [`foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) package. This package supports a `Fold` type expressing all the computations you want to perform as you fold over a `Foldable` container, and how you want to combine/transform the results of those computations. You can write something like

```
import Control.Foldl as L

avg :: (Foldable f, Fractional n) => f n -> n
avg = L.fold $ (/) <$> L.sum <*> (fromIntegral <$> L.length)
```

to produce a function that calculates the mean of the elements of a container. The package is "batteries included", providing a fairly large number of basic operations to use as building blocks, but you can also write your own `Fold`s if you need to. It's also pretty easy to write functions to apply `Fold`s to streaming sources rather than foldable containers if your application demands that.